# PHP mail() send attachment but not html

Tags: php, html, email

I'm trying to send an email with `mail()` function with an `attachment` and `html`.

This is my code :

```
    $from = 'a@a.com';
    $to = 'a@a.com';
    $subject = 'Message from Online Form';

    // main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers = "From: " . $from . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $separator . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message." . $eol;

    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<p>This is a message</p>';
    $message .= '</body></html>';

    // message
    $headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol;
    $headers .= $message . $eol;

    // attachment
    $headers .= "--" . $separator . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $_FILES['image']['name'] . "\"" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol;
    $headers .= $content . $eol;
    $headers .= "--" . $separator . "--";

    mail($to, $subject, "", $headers);
```

So, with this code, I can send my attachment file but my html in `$message` is not in the email...

How can i send file AND html ? Don't know what I missed. Thanks !

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when you can use libraries like SwiftMailer and PHPMailer ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an existing mail librairy. You also could add the body to your mail call :

use

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

instead of

```
mail($to, $subject, "", $headers);
```

Comment: Add $message change nothing

Comment: if you try to send a html mail you also should set your headers in function :

$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;

But I'm not sure that it will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

From This http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php:

```
<?
//define the receiver of the email
$to = 'youraddress@example.com';
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'Test email with attachment';
//create a boundary string. It must be unique
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com";
//add boundary string and mime type specification
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip')));
//define the body of the message.
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering
?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>"

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!!
This is simple text email message.

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p>

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

<?php echo $attachment; ?>
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--

<?php
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer
$message = ob_get_clean();
//send the email
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed"
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed"; 
?>
```